# vectorization of a BETWEEN test

Tags: r, vectorization

I have two vectors `from` and `to` and want to create a matrix of
vectors defined as 1 for `i between from[i] and to[i]` otherwise 0

Here a small example using for loops

```
len <- 5
from <- c(1,3,2,3)
to   <- c(4,3,3,1)

## loop solution
mylist <- list() 
sq <- seq(1,len)

for (i in (1:length(from))) {
   mylist[[i]] <- ifelse(sq >= from[i] & sq <= to[i]  ,1,0)
}
do.call("rbind",mylist)

     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    1    1    1    1    0
[2,]    0    0    1    0    0
[3,]    0    1    1    0    0
[4,]    0    0    0    0    0
```

This works fine, but of course a `vectorized solution` would be more appropriate.
I finally managed a solution shown below, but have some doubts about it.

*Is the function definition necessary or are there possible solutions without a function?*

*Are there better / simpler solution?*

```
delta <- function(from, to)
{
 sq <- seq(1,len)
 return (ifelse(sq >= from & sq <= to ,1,0) )
}
t(mapply( delta , from, to))
```

Comment: I would actually just do what you have done using a loop, via `1* sapply(sq, function(x) x >= from & x <= to)` but you could try `1* ( outer(from , sq, "<=") & outer(to , sq, ">=") )`

Comment: @user20650 excellent proposal as well! Which of the solutions will better scale with large data frame? I mean is there a difference in *user defined* function and *r provided* functions?

Comment: I would think if a for loop  would be fastest, and outer can run into problems with large matrices. Why dont you benchmark the solutions and post the results. [id write the loop as `out <- matrix(0, ncol=length(sq), nrow=length(from)) ;
for(i in seq_along(from)) {
  out[i, ] <- sq >= from[i] & sq <= to[i]  
}` ]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
t(sapply(mapply(`:`, from, to), `%in%`, x = 1:len)) * (from <= to)
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    1    1    1    1    0
[2,]    0    0    1    0    0
[3,]    0    1    1    0    0
[4,]    0    0    0    0    0
```

Comment: excellent! Exact the solution that missed. I never realized that that squared truth is equal one:)

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
res<-matrix(0,nrow=length(from),ncol=len)
res[cbind(
  rep(1:nrow(res),pmax(0,to-from+1)),
  sequence(pmax(0,to-from+1))+rep(from-1,pmax(0,to-from+1))
)]<-1     
#     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
#[1,]    1    1    1    1    0
#[2,]    0    0    1    0    0
#[3,]    0    1    1    0    0
#[4,]    0    0    0    0    0
```